# Manually create ml model in Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-ml

Is there a way to manually create a OneHotEncoderModel without learning it?

This is a quiet simple model and the only learned parameter (as far as I understand) is "categorySizes" which can be accessed using the _java_obj. But, I can not find a way to set it without using OneHotEncoder.fit(...) on a real dataset!

Sample code for what I want to achieve

```
model=OneHotEncoderModel(input='dayOfWeek',output='dayOfWeek_1hot',categorySizes=[7])
model.transform(data)
```